# Python-Code in Wordpress: Some Quotation Marks are displayed "lower-case"

Tags: python, wordpress, quotation-marks

I am writing several Tutorials for the Python API we are using in our company. The website used is designed with Wordpress. I can write an article and in the editor everything looks good, but when I look at the published version the first quotation marks of each "String" are written low (as this is invalid in python).
[image: Output displayed on the Website]

In the editor:

[image: This is how it is inserted in the editor]

Looking at "code" set in the editor, I created a "blockquote" to mark the code as the "" tag or similar tags won't work. I set a certain stylesheet as well, but its a very simple one:
[image]

[image]

Can anyone tell me a trick to make ALL quotation marks appear as UPPER marks? By the way I am not allowed to use webfonts we were adviced this was not allowed in terms of DSGVO and our terms of use...

Comment: Almost certainly caused by locale options. Some "clever" mechanism makes you use German-style quotation marks. Note that just changing the language might produce correctly-looking (but just as incorrect) ‟unicode quotation marks”.

Comment: That might really be. I just checked the page has de-DE set as locale option. Is there any way to tell a certain class of objects to ignore the locale? Or is there a common font that doesn't support these quotation marks? Or is there some kind of unicode character code that I could enter? Do you or just anybody, know something to eventually work around that problem?

Comment: It's certainly not a font issue and the correct unicode is just good old ASCII 0x22. Your source files are okay. I'd guess there's some postprocessing going on to prettify quotes when you upload. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with Wordpress but that's where I'd start digging.

Comment: That's why I personally don't like page-generators like wordpress... they do what they want but do won't tell you... Thanks to all your advices Friedrich, I'll keep on searching. Would just be nice the "pre" was allowed, but it gets removed automatically. I just tried using different quotation mark like looking signs in unicode, but even these get automatically converted to those shown above. ...Page-Generators...